# compare two data frame column and print the uncommon values from df1

Tags: python, pandas

```
df1                df2
p_id                id
1                    4
2                    5                  
3                    6
4                    7
5                    8
6                    9
```

result should be

```
new df
column
1
2
3
```

please help with pandas code to figure out

Comment: i need unmatched values alone from df1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it:

```
df[~(df['p_id'].isin(df2['id']))]

    p_id
0   1
1   2
2   3
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the answer

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({"p_id":[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
df_2 =pd.DataFrame({"id":[4,5,6,7,8,9]})
s1 = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, how='left', left_on=["p_id"], right_on=["id"])
s1 = s1[s1.id.isna()]
s1 = s1.drop(columns="id")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`np.setdiff1d`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html?highlight=setdiff1d#numpy.setdiff1d).

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'columns':np.setdiff1d(df1['p_id'], df2['id'])})

   columns
0        1
1        2
2        3
```

You can also make `p_id`, `id` as index as use [`pd.Index.difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html)

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Index(df1['p_id']).difference(df2['id']))
```

Using `set.difference`

```
pd.DataFrame(list(set(df1['p_id']).difference(df2['id'])), columns = ['columns'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
intersected_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner')
```

You can simply merge the dataframes to get the intersection of both frames. Make sure both columns are named same. In your case, you probable need to rename both column as **p_id**

Answer (score 0):

Use `.isin()` and mask unwanted

```
df1[df2.id.isin(df1.p_id)]


   p_id
0     1
1     2
2     3
```